# Matching text files from a list of system numbers

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have ~ 60K bibliographic records, which can be identified by system number. These records also hold full-text (individudal text files named by system number).

I have lists of system numbers in bunches of 5K and I need to find a way to copy only the text files from each 5K list.
All text files are stored in a directory (`/fulltext`) and are named something along these lines: 
`014776324.txt.`

The 5k lists are plain text stored in separated directories (e.g. `/5k_list_1`, `5k_list_2`, ...), where each system number matches to a `.txt` file.

For example: `bibliographic record 014776324` matches to `014776324.txt`.

I am struggling to find a way to copy into the 5k_list_* folders only the corresponding text files.

Any idea?

Thanks indeed,

Comment: err, sorry what do you want from us? A script?

Comment: Do yo want to copy only the files that have their names listed inside a text file which is a kind of index?

Comment: You can do this with AWK and probably GREP, but I'm having trouble understanding what do you want to copy. Can you explain further? Thanks

Comment: @trojanfoe, no I don't want a ready-to-use script.

Comment: @Dropout, I will look into the AWK utility. Thanks!

Comment: @Atropo Yes, exactly what I would like to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume we invoke the following script this way:

```
./the-script.sh fulltext 5k_list_1 5k_list_2 [...]
```

Or more succinctly:

```
./the-script.sh fulltext 5k_list_*
```

Then try using this (totally untested) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu # enable error checking

src_dir=$1 # first argument is where to copy files from
shift 1

for list_dir; do # implicitly consumes remaining args
    while read bibliographic record sys_num rest; do
        cp "$src_dir/$sys_num.txt" "$list_dir/"
    done < "$list_dir/list.txt"
done
```